# How can i inject the AntiForgery token?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

While using within my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery
@inject IAntiforgery AntiForgery;
```

I expect the `RequestVerificationToken` to be present at the Request headers.

But expecations are not met. While inspecting the Request headers,
the `RequestVerificationToken` is not present at all.

Is this somehow related to `net Core 3.0`, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a ajax query to send the antiforgeryToken follow the steps below. else the RequestVerificationToken will be automatically added to the formData

Add the following to your cshtml and js

```cs
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}

<form>
      <input type="hidden" id="RequestVerificationToken"
               name="RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()" />
</form>
```

Add this to your XMLHttpRequest instance

```js
xhttp.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", 
                    document.getElementById('RequestVerificationToken').value);
```

Comment: Need a coffee break. Had not included in POST.... headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },